# How to Grab this using Regex?

Tags: php, regex

How to grab only name J.J. Abrams, Pippa Anderson on regex ???

```
 <header class="ipl-header">
        <div class="ipl-header__content">        
        <h4 name="producers" id="producers" class="ipl-header__content ipl-list-title">
            Produced by
        </h4>
</div>
        <a class="ipl-header__edit-link" href="https://contribute.imdb.com/updates?update=tt2527336:producers">Edit</a>
    </header>

    <table class="subpage_data spFirst crew_list">
        <tbody>
                    <tr class="even">
                        <td class="name">
                            <a href="/name/nm0009190/?ref_=tt_rv"
>J.J. Abrams</a>
                        </td>
                            <td>...</td>
                            <td>executive producer</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd">
                        <td class="name">
                            <a href="/name/nm0027297/?ref_=tt_rv"
>Pippa Anderson</a>
                        </td>
                            <td>...</td>
                            <td>co-producer</td>
                    </tr>


                    </tbody>
                    </table>
```

il try using this code, but not working... please help me to fixed this. thanks

```
$arr['producers'] = $this->match_all_key_value('/<td class="name"><a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/ms', $this->match('/Produced by<\/a><\/h4>(.*?)<\/table>/ms', $html, 1));
$arr['producers'] = array_slice($arr['producers'], 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing html is really a task for a dom parser like  [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or for example [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) explains why.

If you want to do it in regex, another option (when running PHP 5.2.4 or later) could be using `\K` in your regex.

What you could do is match right before the the data that you are looking for. Then reset the starting point of the reported match using `\K`, match the data that you are looking for and using a positive lookahead for the closing anchor tag.

[`<td class="name">\n\s+<a[^>]+>\K.*(?=<\/a>)`](https://regex101.com/r/d8uV18/1)

```
$pattern = "/<td class=\"name\">\n\s+<a[^>]+>\K.*(?=<\/a>)/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);
```

The array would be then in `$matches[0]`

Explanation

- Match `<td class="name">`
- Match a new line `\n`
- Match one or more white spaces `\s+`
- Match `<a`
- Match not a `>` on or more times [^>]+
- Match `>`
- Then reset the starting point of the reported match with `\K`
- Match .* any character zero or more times
- A positive lookahead `(?=)`
- Asserting the what follows is </a> `<\/a>`
- Close the positive lookahead `)`

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/sNZWk)

Without `\K`, you could capture your values in a capturing group like `(.*)`

The regex would then look like:

[`<td class="name">\n\s+<a[^>]+>(.*)(?=<\/a>)`](https://regex101.com/r/Wtyb4I/1/)

```
$pattern = "/<td class=\"name\">\n\s+<a[^>]+>(.*)(?=<\/a>)/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);
```

The array would be then in `$matches[1]`

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/B5I1R)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```
preg_match_all( "#<a href=\"/name/.*?>(.*?)</a>#is", $html, $results );
$arr['producers'] = array_pop( $results );
print_r( $arr['producers'] );
```

It's looking for links that have a reference starting with /name, then grabbing everything inside the link tabs. This is assuming there aren't any other links on the page that have references starting with /name in the path and not wanted. If so, you may have to tweak that part of the expression to be more specific.

Comment: Im use to wordpress...  so not need print_r( $producers );

Comment: the print_r is just for testing purposes to see the contents of what was captured. It wouldn't be used in an actual PHP script. Did the rest help I hope?